# rails order 2 columns based on lower value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out how to phrase this question properly.

How to write the `order()` to get my products sorted by `(discounted_price || price) DESC` ?

| id | price | discounted_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 3 | null |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |

Should return the ids 1,3,2

How would you correctly phrase this question?

Comment: You should be able to do it with `order('COALESCE(discounted_price, price) DESC')`

Comment: See documentation, here's MySQL, but it works similarly in other DBs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: "Should return the ids 1,3,2" they are in ascending order, though.

Comment: If you're using Postgres and want to get fancy you can create a generated column. For example `price_x decimal GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(discounted_price, price)) STORED` . Then you simply do `order(price_x: :desc)` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COALESCE:

```
Product.order(
  # COALESCE(discounted_price, price) DESC
  Product.arel_table.then { |p| p.coalesce(p[:discounted_price], p[:price]) }.desc
)
```

This function is fairly standardized across RDBMS and returns the first non-null argument.

Comment: Since `coalesce` is a `NamedFunction`, you could just tag the `desc` on to the end of the block or inside the block e.g. `.then { |p| p.coalesce(p[:discounted_price], p[:price]).desc }`.

Comment: True @engineersmnky - its just easier this way if you then want to exact it into a method which takes the direction as an option.

Comment: @engineersmnky ah, you're right. It's generating the wrong SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do something like:
`order(discounted_price: :desc, price: :desc)`

Comment: That doesn't actually do the same thing.